# Разрабатываю браузерную карточную игру. Проблема во взаимодействии пользователей

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Разрабатываю браузерную карточную игру. Сама игра написана на html+css+javascript (jQuery). Но мини-сайт с игрой конечно же на php. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как первому игроку узнавать, как походил второй. Через куки, сессии и базу данных узнать не выйдет. Копался в интернете и увидел слово "Сокеты", но нигде ничего нужного не описывалось (Может я правда не то вводил). Кто сталкивался с подобным или просто знает как это можно реализовать, помогите. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а если в процессе игры, записывать в базу ход событий, например, начинают играть Юра и Антон -> Создается запись в базе что игра началась -> Когда Юра или Антон сделал ход записываем в таблицу значение 1 - это будет значить что Юра сделал ход -> Проверяем значение - если = 1 -> Передаем ход Антону -> Значение в базе для хода Юры ставим = 2, это значит что ходит Антон - не даем ходить Юре. После хода Антона записываем ему 2, Юре = 0

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону Socket.io (http://socket.io/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала опишу самый простой вариант, потом будут варианты посложнее. Итак, самое первое, что в любом случае нужно сделать - это то, что сервер должен знать, чей сейчас ход. Например, хранить в базе. Так как один и тот же игрок в принципе может играть несколько партий одновременно, то есть смысл хранить таблицу "активных игр", где будут id двух игроков и номер текущего игрока.

Когда один игрок сделал свой ход, он отправляет запрос и сервер, проверив его, отсылает подтверждение хода. А сам в базе обновляет (то есть просто делает update для нужной записи). Второй игрок в этот момент находился в режиме ожидания хода. В этом режиме он просто делает обычные запросы раз в секунду (или может и раз в две секунды) с запросом "чей ход". Сервер просто идет в базу и присылает номер текущего игрока (серверу в принципе побоку, кто послал этот запрос, хотя клиент может присылать свой номер, а сервер посмотрит в базу и решит - его или не его ход). Клиент сравнивает его с своим и понимает, когда наступил его черед.

С этим запросом есть маленькая особенность. Я думаю, что лучше его делать POST запросом, а не GET. Потому что GET кешируется, а игра то динамичная.

POST запросы по стандарту не кешируются и сервер всегда будет присылать актуальное состояние. (одна малоизвесная яблочная компания на своих телефонах одно время сделала кеширование POST запросов... это было весело).

Этот подход в принципе полностью работоспособный и широко применяется. Скажу даже больше, долгое время большинство онлайн чатов было построено по этой модели. Поэтому, поискав примеры подобных чатов, можно получить работающий сервер и почти готовых клиентов.

Через какое то время придумали, что можно не просто дергать запросы, а дергать и ждать чуточку. Если у сервера что то появилось, он пришлет. Называется это Comet. [Здесь](http://spectrox.ru/blog/comet-theory-beginning/) найдете пример на javascript+php.

Сейчас, в наш развитый век придумали постоянные подключения к серверу (да, они и раньше существовали, но вот только браузеры с ними тяжело справлялись, приходилось флеш применять и другие технологии). Теперь почти все браузеры поддерживают технологию под названием [websocket](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). Эта технология как раз и создана для задач как Ваша. Клиент и сервер держат подключенным канал связи и сервер спокойно может послать клиенту нужную информацию. На хабре есть [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/) на эту тему.

Comment: "*С этим запросом есть маленькая особенность. Я думаю, что лучше его делать POST запросом, а не GET. Потому что GET кешируется, а игра то динамичная.*" - nooooooooooooo, лучше просто верные заголовки отдавать и спонсировать рандомным гет-параметром.

Comment: можно добавить временную метку (timestamp) в запрос.
А вот заголовки... браузер имеет полное право кешировать GET запрос, если url не поменялся. Да, я понимаю, есть разные заголовки для этого, но после того, как фаерфокс перестал удалять куки, которые в всех остальных браузерах удалятся после закрытия...

Comment: "*браузер имеет полное право кешировать GET запрос, если url не поменялся.*" - для гарантированного изменения урла, и, следовательно, самого ресурса и нужен случайный гет-параметр

Answer (score 0):

Через nodejs и сокеты, могу простенькие примеры дать  https://nodejs.org/en/ 
http://socket.io/